# Array initialization with const variable

Tags: c, gcc

I was coding a mini GTK+2.0 game when i had a problem. When i write this :

```
const unsigned LABEL_NUMBER = 4;
const char *LABEL_TEXT[4] = {
                              "Five or More",
                              "By ... "
                              "& ...",
                              "April 2016",
                              "~~ Thanks for playing ~~"
                           };
```

There is no problem. But when i write this :

```
const unsigned LABEL_NUMBER = 4;
const char *LABEL_TEXT[LABEL_NUMBER] = {
                                          "Five or More",
                                          "By ... "
                                          "& ...",
                                          "April 2016",
                                          "~~ Thanks for playing ~~"
                                       };
```

gcc answers :

```
source/gui.c: In function ‘create_about_window’:
source/gui.c:202:4: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    const char *LABEL_TEXT[LABEL_NUMBER] = {
    ^
source/gui.c:203:34: error: excess elements in array initializer [-Werror]
                                  "Five or More",
                                  ^
source/gui.c:203:34: note: (near initialization for ‘LABEL_TEXT’)
source/gui.c:204:34: error: excess elements in array initializer [-Werror]
                                  "By ... & ..."
                                  ^
source/gui.c:204:34: note: (near initialization for ‘LABEL_TEXT’)
source/gui.c:206:34: error: excess elements in array initializer [-Werror]
                                  "April 2016",
                                  ^
source/gui.c:206:34: note: (near initialization for ‘LABEL_TEXT’)
source/gui.c:207:34: error: excess elements in array initializer [-Werror]
                                  "~~ Thanks for playing ~~"
                                  ^
source/gui.c:207:34: note: (near initialization for ‘LABEL_TEXT’)
```

So i just want to know why gcc displays this errors while i use a constant unsigned integer to set the array size ?

Comment: [Works on my machine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb6ad14a4c89e222)

Comment: It's required behaviour for C compilers; `const unsigned LABEL_NUMBER = 4;` is a variable — albeit one that doesn't change value.  Arrays come in two flavours; those with a size fixed by a compile time integer constant (which can be initialized), and those with a variable size (which cannot be initialized).  Because, in the terms of the C compiler (C standard), the latter is a variable, you have a variably-modified array and can't use initializers.  In case of doubt, use `enum { LABEL_NUMBER = 4 };`.  That will appear in your symbol table but can be used in array dimensions.

Comment: It's curious to use string concatenation on the two shortest strings in the initializers.  (`"By ... " "& ...",` is a single string because there's no comma after the second double quote.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok tanks i've understood :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In fact the were more text but you can try without concatenation, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It was only a comment — it isn't formally wrong, just a little unusual.  And apt to cause confusion as the comments in @haccks answer shows.

Comment: @MooingDuck this is a C question; you're using a C++ compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable length arrays can't be initialised using initializers.

C11 - §6.7.9/3:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is **not a variable length array type**.

Comment: I'm sort of shocked that it compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb6ad14a4c89e222

Comment: @MooingDuck; In c++, `const` qualified objects are treated as real constant literals (with some exceptions). You are compiling using `g++`. It's a C++ compiler.

Comment: But i don't understand why LABEL_TEXT[] is a VLA, char *LABEL_TEXT[const ...] == char *(LABEL_TEXT[const ...]) no ?

Comment: @Maxime; In C, `const` qualified objects are not constant literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can define LABEL_NUMBER as macro:

```
#define LABEL_NUMBER 4
```

That way the LABEL_NUMBER

```
const char *LABEL_TEXT[LABEL_NUMBER]
```

will be replaced at pre-processing phase by defined macro value which
will produce:

```
const char *LABEL_TEXT[4]
```

for a compiler to compile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it isn't really what i was asking :)